# Granting access to YouTube Movies

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

We want to grant access to some users so they can view parts of some YouTube movies (from Play Store, not public videos), but we can't find any relevant API.

The workflow could be something like: user wants to see 1st video, so we query the YouTube API and we identify ourselves, then we request for an Authorization token, we return that token to the user and they will be redirected to the Video (only some specific minutes), without any special action on their part.

Does anyone know if there's an advanced API that goes beyond embedding public videos?

Answer (score 0):

[Video resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource)
there is also status.privacyStatus :  private, public, unlisted

Unlisted videos can be seen by anyone with the link to the video.  You should be able to embed this.

So basically you can take the id of the video and create a link to it like this.

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={id}

You wont need to identify yourself as long as you know the id of said video.